# Ant: how to call a script from another scriptdef with an attribute

Tags: javascript, ant

I want to call a script from one another:

```
<scriptdef name="script-to-call" language="javascript">
  <attribute name="myattr" />
  <![CDATA[
    var myattr = attributes.get("myattr");
    // ... do something
  ]]>
</scriptdef>
```

I try this, but I got

> TypeError: Cannot find function setMyattr

```
<scriptdef name="caller-script" language="javascript">
  <![CDATA[
    var task = project.createTask("script-to-call");
    task.setMyattr("some value");
    task.perform();
  ]]>
</scriptdef>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution:

```
var task = project.createTask("script-to-call");
task.setDynamicAttribute("myattr", "some value");
task.perform();
```